# Angular 2 - How to modify an input B in ngOnChange (triggered by changing input A)

Tags: angular, triggers, onchange, observable, angular2-docheck

I have a component with an input and a variable:

```
@Input() data: string[];
@Input() val: string = '';

ngOnChanges(changes: SimpleChanges) {
    for (let propName in changes) {
       if (propName == 'data') {
            this.val = 'hello';
       }
    }
}
```

The problem is, i need to change the input **val** when **data** is changed. But i have the following error:

```
Expression has changed after it was checked. Previous value: 'false'. Current value: 'true'.
```

Thanks !

Answer (score 0):

It's easier to create a setter

```ts
_data: string[];
@Input() set data(val: string[]) {
  this._data = val;
  this.val = 'abc'
  // this.cdRef.detectChanges();
}
get data() { return this._data; }

@Input() val: string = '';
```

If you still get the error then add

```ts
constructor(private cdRef:ChangeDetectorRef) {}
```

and comment in the commented out line in the setter above.

Comment: Thanks but I've used **this.cdRef.detectChanges()** but still have this error.

Comment: What value do you change from `false` to `true`.